# Какая марка смартфонов лучше подходит для debugging в Android studio?

Tags: android, отладка

Решил перейти с отладки на эмуляторе к реальному девайсу. Пробовал на своем Xiaomi, там стоит защита, заниматься отладкой можно только с китайского прокси.
У каких марок телефонов нет защит такого типа? Или что посоветуете, какие девайсы посоветуете для отладок?
Думаю в сторону Samsung

Comment: какая защита? о чём ты? у меня был ксяоми, никаких проблем

Comment: у меня Xiaomi Mi Pro 2017 года, при нажатии на кнопку разрешения установки приложений через usb вылетает алерт `the device is temporary restricted 3-2` и все, в андроид студии его не видно. ну и режим разработчика у меня включен был, всегда включен. гуглил ошибку - пишут типо через прокси китая телефон надо использовать

Comment: понял, значит не у всех xiaomi блок стоит. а какой у вас ксиаоми был?)

Comment: сомневаюсь что тут дело в прокси, попробуйте отозвать права на отладку и снова с нуля подключить тел к пк

Comment: Xiaomi Redmi Note 7

Comment: попробовал опять с нуля права включить, еще телефон перезагрузил - тот же алерт выскакивает. Наверное это изза того что телефон старый, и у относительно ранних моделей ксиаоми стоит блок такой

Comment: Вот в интернетах пишут, и наши и пендосы: Выключить wifi
включить мобильную связь в параметрах разработчика
После этого установка через USB и отладка по USB начали работать.

Comment: хех, пишет - `подключитесь к сети и попробуйте снова` (установил режим в 
 самолете, и отдельно сеть отключал с wifi). как прошлый алерт выскакивал, теперь так выскакивает, (оба раз Toast выскакивал)

Comment: вообщем у телефона ограничение на установку со студии. а так логи могу смотреть с компуктера, которые идут с телефона, придется по bluetooth передвать приложухи

Comment: У меня Xiaomi Redmi 6а все работает